# Angular and cypress testing. How to test the effect of an http response on the component

Tags: angular, cypress

I just cant get this right. I have manage to test many thing but what I cant get right is to test if a form is visible after an http request.

I have this as a simple explanation below of what I am trying to do.

I have an ngOnInit which fires a **connectForm** function (my test checks that its fired at least once) yay!
Then, when the connectForm is fired, I do a http request to see if query string id is valid.
I have written a test to fake this, and it works but how do I ensure that its a success so I can display the form?

How do I test that the form is visible once I have done a fake request?

Angular sample code is below

```
isConnected(response){
    this.showForm = true;
  }

  connectForm(dataToBeSent){

    const url = ${this.apiUrl}/verify-form;

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    this.http.post(url, dataToBeSent, { headers })
    .subscribe(
      {
        next: (response) => {
          this.isConnected(response);
        },
        error: (err: any) => { 
          this.cantConnect(err);
        },
        complete: () => { }
      }
    );
  }


  ngOnInit() { 
    this.connectForm({data: queryid})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems you have to do this with e2e testing rather. Component testing with urls is not advisable.